# Selenium and bs4 for Raspberry Pi Webscraping?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am about to drive myself mad with this problem. After a few days, I have gotten my Raspberry Pi up and running with Selenium using Chromium and its webdriver. It pulls up the webpage and even scrolls has I have instructed it to do. The only thing it is not doing is finding the class I'm specifying. It's a little complex because I am trying to scrape the Twitter Reply section which has endless scrolling, therefore I have to use Selenium to get the page_source for each scroll for it to grab the usernames. It works on my Desktop when I run the script, but not on my pi. What kinds of things could make this happen? Here is some of the script:

```
import requests, time, botometer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = ("https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1265827032707072000")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    'chrome/driver/here')

def scroll_to_bottom(driver):
        # Empty list for all the usernames scraped
        FULL_LIST = []
        bots = []

        old_position = 0
        new_position = None

        while new_position != old_position:
            # Get old scroll position
                old_position = driver.execute_script(
                ("return (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ?"
                " window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement ||"
                " document.body.parentNode || document.body);"))

                # Scrapes usernames from current scrolls
                html = driver.page_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
                usernameSoup = soup.find_all(
                "div", class_="css-901oao css-bfa6kz r-111h2gw r-18u37iz r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0")
                list_of_usernames = [x.text for x in usernameSoup]

                # Prints current loot of usernames
                text = ', '.join(list_of_usernames)
                print("SCROLLINGS LOOT:", text)
                print("LEN:", len(list_of_usernames))

                # Extends master list of usernames
                FULL_LIST.extend(list_of_usernames)

                # Deletes any duplicates in FULL_LIST
                FULL_LIST = list(dict.fromkeys(FULL_LIST))

                # Sleep and Scroll
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.execute_script((
                "var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement ||"
                " document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop ="
                " scrollingElement.scrollHeight;"))
                # Get new position
                new_position = driver.execute_script(
                ("return (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ?"
                " window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement ||"
                " document.body.parentNode || document.body);"))
                print("FULL LIST: ", len(FULL_LIST))

driver.get(url)
scroll_to_bottom(driver)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I have the impression that the CSS classes are not constant. I've tried your code and there are variations. I see three possibilities: using a looser CSS selector, using an XPATH selector so you don't depend on class names, or use the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-show-id). The API would be a much better option provided it can return all the items you need. Then you can use the `requests` module instead of Selenium. By the way you are importing the `requests` module but as far as I can tell it's unneeded.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried the Twitter API but as far as I can tell, it does not return the list of users that are replying to tweets. It seems like the Twitter API only returns basic information specifics about a specific account.